# Type Error: undefined is not and object, error comes while mapping the data from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, typeerror

I am first filtering my data coming from API and then storing it in a const. I am trying to map that object stored in the constant but I am facing this error[image] 
My Code is:

```
secondPicker = () => {
    if (this.state.PickerValueHolder === 'Punjab') {
        const space = this.state.myData.filter(x => x.label === 'Punjab');
        console.log(space.children);
        return (<Picker
                style={styles.dropDown}
                label="Select City"
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ PickerValueHolderCity: itemValue })}
                selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolderCity}
            >
                {space.children.map((item, key) => (
                    <Picker.Item label={item.label} value={item.value} key={key} />)
                )}
            </Picker>
        )
    }
    else{return} 
}
```

when I console log 'space' I get the following data:
[image]

And the API I am getting my data from is: https://retailsolution.pk/api/countrywise

Comment: `filter` will return an array, and then you try to access the `children` property of this array and use `map` on it. Is that really what you want? Should it not be just `space.map(...)`?

Comment: @Tholle I have added the picture of the data of my space constant. Don't you think 'space.children.map' is a right approach?

Comment: Great, thanks. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering out all elements in the array that has a label `Punjab` into a new array. If you want to use this approach, you must access the first element in this new array and `map` over the `children` array in that object.

```
space[0].children.map((item, key) => ( /* ... */ ))
```

You could alternatively use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) so that you get the desired object in your `space` variable instead of an array.

```
secondPicker = () => {
  if (this.state.PickerValueHolder === "Punjab") {
    const space = this.state.myData.find(x => x.label === "Punjab");

    return (
      <Picker
        style={styles.dropDown}
        label="Select City"
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
          this.setState({ PickerValueHolderCity: itemValue })
        }
        selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolderCity}
      >
        {space.children.map((item, key) => (
          <Picker.Item label={item.label} value={item.value} key={key} />
        ))}
      </Picker>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Great Man..!!  adding [0] worked for me, not sure about the other method,but 1st one worked

Comment: @abbujan Great! Either one will work, it's more a matter of taste.